# How to use jquery.dirtyforms with SweetAlert v2 Dialog

Tags: jquery, sweetalert

I am able to get jquery.dirtyforms to work with the default dialog box but am not able to get it working using the SweetAlert dialog box. Here is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js?v=3"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.1.10/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.dirtyforms/2.0.0/jquery.dirtyforms.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="aspnetForm" runat="server" method="post">
        <div>

            <h1>Dirty Forms Test Page</h1>

            <input id="input" type="text" runat="server" /><br />
            <br />
            <input id="input2" type="text" runat="server" /><br />
            <br />
            <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
            <br /><br />
            <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a separate JS file. In that, if I uncomment the $('form').dirtyForms(); line, and comment out the custom Sweetalert dialog, it works.  If I comment out the first and uncomment the SweetAlert code, I get the popup dialog but if I choose the option to proceed and leave the page, nothing happens, and it stays on the page.  Here's my JS code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    //This works with standard dialog box
    //$('form').dirtyForms();

    // This look nicer but does not work
    // SweetAlert dialog
    $('form').dirtyForms({
        dialog: {
            open: function (choice, message) {

                choice.bindEnterKey = true;
                choice.staySelector = '.dirty-dialog .dirty-stay,.blockOverlay';
                choice.proceedSelector = '.dirty-dialog .dirty-proceed';

                Swal.fire({
                    title: "Are you sure?",
                    text: message,
                    icon: "question",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    focusCancel: true,
                    confirmButtonText: 'Leave',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6'
                }
                ).then((result) => {
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        choice.proceed = true;
                        choice.commit();
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This is what the default dialog box, that works looks like:

[image]

This is what the SweetAlert dialog, that doesn't work looks like:

[image]

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Changed the SweetAlert code and was able to make it work. Removed the fat arrow syntax on the handler (replaced with function(result) {) and passing this.event to commit call: choice.commit(this.event)

```
// SweetAlert dialog
$('form').dirtyForms({
    dialog: {
        open: function (choice, message) {

            choice.bindEnterKey = true;
            choice.staySelector = '.dirty-dialog .dirty-stay,.blockOverlay';
            choice.proceedSelector = '.dirty-dialog .dirty-proceed';

            Swal.fire({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: message,
                icon: "question",
                showCancelButton: true,
                focusCancel: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Leave',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6'
            }
            ).then( function(result) {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    choice.proceed = true;
                    choice.commit( this.event);
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks for tip to Matt Harper